# Equivalent of a recurrence sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, recurrence-relations

Let $x_{0} = 2$ and $x_{n+1} = x_{n} + \ln(x_{n})$, how can I find an asymptotic equivalent of this sequence say, to the third term? (This is not homework, it was a problem in the Oral Examination 2010 of Ecole Centrale).

Answer (score 2):

My approach would be:

1. Integrate the "continuous version", to get $x(t) = t \log t - t.$ So your $x_n = n \log n - n + \epsilon(n),$ then plug into the recurrence to see what it tells you about $\epsilon(n).$

Comment: but why we should have $x_n = n \log n - n + \epsilon(n)$ ?

Comment: Because the recurrence is a "discrete version" of the ODE $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \log x.$$

Comment: I'm interested in the completion of your method.  My approach indicates $x_n = n\log n + n\log\log n - n + o(n)$, though I'm having trouble justifying it rigorously.

Comment: @AntonioVargas OK, I will try to work it out...

Comment: Ah, I think I see what the issue is.  The system $x_{n+1} - x_n = \log x_n$ isn't a discrete version of $\frac{dx}{dt} = \log t$, it's a discrete version of $\frac{dx}{dt} = \log x$.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Oops, you are completely right (not thinking straight today). Of course, that justifies your asymptotics idea.